# Convert BitmapDrawable to Bitmap

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap, bitmapdrawable

In my project a bitmap gets filled with text and another bitmap, the method to add the text to the bitmap returns a BitmapDrawable.

I want to save this BitmapDrawable as a pdf file, so I can email the original bitmap, with text and other image(s) added.

For this, I'll need a regular Bitmap instead of a BitmapDrawable.
I can't seem to find any answers on this, because I don't have a reference to a drawable in a drawable folder, I just have a BitmapDrawable to work with.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[BitmapDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) support a getter for the bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
```

Comment: Really simple, but the million dollar answer for me right now! Thanks!